# Adding in "else" makes my for loop not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to coding and have a list of lists that I need to search. 
I want to see what lists contained in the larger list have the variable full_choice as the 3rd item in the sequence. 
All lists that contain third_choice i need to print to a txt file.

the code below works and adds exactly what I need it to to the file, however I need the function to start again if there is no match for the variable full_choice.

```
def display_instructor_txt():
    file_name = input('type in the name of the file you want to create do not include .txt')
    file_name_full = file_name + '.txt'
    new_file = open(file_name_full,'w')
    first_choice = input('type in the first name of the instructor you want to filter by ')
    last_choice = input('type in the last name of the instructor you want to filter by ')
    full_choice = first_choice[0].upper() + first_choice[1:].lower() + last_choice[0].upper() + last_choice[1:].lower()
    for course in all_courses_list:
        if course[2].replace(" ","").replace(",","") == full_choice:
            course_st = ''.join(course)
            new_file.write(course_st.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'').replace('\\n','').replace(" ", ", "))
    else:
        print('please try again')
        display_instructor_txt()
```

I have tried inserting an else: at the end of the code however while that has ends up creating the file it doesn't write anything to it.

Comment: What code exactly was written after the `else`?

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: else:
    print('name not found please try again')
    dispaly_instructor_txt()

Comment: @AndreaRichmond: Edit the question and add it there. In python indentation is significant, and it's really important that the code sample in the question is exactly the same as what's causing the bug.

Comment: What is the `''''''''''''` in your code supposed to be for? And is that correctly indented?

Comment: Please note that indentation matters in Python.  `for...else` is a completely different construct than `if...else`.

Comment: in the code the'''''''''''' isn't there, and thats where that line is indented to. I am having a hard time figuring our how to properly format things on this website.... my bad.

Comment: I have edited the code best I can, it does not work if I use for...else or if...else.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the code, but it looks like you're recursively calling display_instructor_txt from inside the for-loop. Are you sure you shouldn't be doing some sort of checks before starting the for-loop?

Comment: The purpose of the for loop is to check if a word (variable full_choice is present in a list or lists.)

If it s it is present I want it to print the list(s) that it is in to a txt file, if it is not I want the function to start again

Answer (score 0):

As @Haken Lid suspected, please fix indentation:

```
for course in all_courses_list:
    if course[2].replace(" ","").replace(",","") == full_choice:
        course_st = ''.join(course)
        new_file.write(course_st.replace('[','').replace(']','').
                       replace("'",'').replace('\\n','').replace(" ", ", "))
    else:
        print('please try again')
        display_instructor_txt()
```

Comment: I changed the indentation to what you did but it still is not working for me, if i remove that else line it works

Comment: Please check what `print(course[2].replace(" ","").replace(",",""))` and `print(full_choice)` returns?

Comment: they print the same thing following the         

if course[2].replace(" ","").replace(",","") == full_choice:

Could it be that as the for loop cycles through the list it initially does not find them to be equal and therefore triggers the else.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to fix your indentation. I'm guessing you wanted something like this:

```
def display_instructor_txt():
    file_name = input('type in the name of the file you want to create do not include .txt')
    file_name_full = file_name + '.txt'
    new_file = open(file_name_full,'w')
    first_choice = input('type in the first name of the instructor you want to filter by ')
    last_choice = input('type in the last name of the instructor you want to filter by ')
    full_choice = first_choice[0].upper() + first_choice[1:].lower() + last_choice[0].upper() + last_choice[1:].lower()
    for course in all_courses_list:
        if course[2].replace(" ","").replace(",","") == full_choice:
            course_st = ''.join(course)
            new_file.write(course_st.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'').replace('\\n','').replace(" ", ", "))
        else:
            print('please try again')
            display_instructor_txt()
```

I just moved the `else` block forward to align with the `if` block you had a few lines before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried that and it still does not work, if I get rid of the else entirely it does work....

Comment: @AndreaRichmond Maybe edit the `else` to something more direct? Like `else if . . .` could have a better effect.